# Template helper not ready even though it should be

Tags: javascript, highcharts, meteor

Very hard to come up with a good title for this question...

**The error**

I am experiencing some strange problem that results in the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Component> has no method 'someHelper'
```

even though I explicitly check for the template helper 'someHelper' to be ready. The weird part is that this *only* happens when meteor restarts due to code changes (and *not* if I stop and start meteor manually). The error occurs exactly once, if I refresh the page everything works as expected. I tested in Chrome and Firefox, same behavior.

**The code**

Let me explain (all code below is in **client.js**):

I have some plotting code that needs a div in the template `someTemplate` to render a chart to (Highcharts API). The plotting is done in the template helper `Template.someTemplate.someHelper()`.

The plot should reactively update so I have something like this

```
Deps.autorun(function () {
  // ... some code

  // I am expecting the template not to be ready so I use a session variable to check
  if (Session.get("someTemplateRendered")){
    // The check above should be sufficient but after experiencing the error I added an
    // additional check
    if (typeof Template.someTemplate.someHelper != undefined){ 
      Template.historychart.someHelper(); // this is the line with the error (sometimes)
    }
  }
});
```

To set the session variable I do:

```
Template.someTemplate.rendered = function() {
  Session.set("someTemplateRendered", true);
  // (nothing else in this rendered callback)
};
```

Even more strangely, if I pause execution in the line where the error occurs and execute

```
typeof Template.someTemplate.someHelper
```

in the JS console I get: `"undefined"`.

How can this possibly be? I am explicitly checking that `Template.someTemplate.someHelper` is not undefined!

I am out of ideas and would be very happy about some suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `typeof blah` where `blah` is not defined is the string `"undefined"`, not the value `undefined`. It turns out that `undefined == "undefined"` is false.

```
// in a Javascript console, where there is no variable 'qwerty'
typeof qwerty != undefined
// > true
typeof qwerty != "undefined"
// > false
```

By the way, Session variables are preserved through hot code reload, so after HCR, `Session.get("someTemplateRendered")` is still true even if `someTemplate` hasn't rendered yet, as long as it was rendered before the HCR. That's why that autorun triggers immediately when the page reloads due to HCR.

One question: why even bother with the Session variable and the autorun? What's wrong with this?

```
Template.someTemplate.rendered = function() {
  // Set up the chart
}
```

A template helper is not really the appropriate place for that function; template helpers generally do not have side effects and are generally only called by templates (or sometimes other helpers).

Comment: About your question: I agree that my current solution is not the nicest. The thing is that I also want to update my chart by calling `someHelper` again and again. Manually calling `Template.rendered`  seems odd, don't you think? Also the updating depends on a reactive data source, hence the autorun. Moreover I was running into the issue that `Template.rendered` was called before the data source my chart depends on was ready. Overall it was difficult to integrate Highcharts which endorses "jquery-esque" style that is discouraged by meteor. Suggestions to clean this up are more than welcome :)

Comment: The way I handle this kind of thing is to create an autorun inside the `Template.x.rendered` (and stop it again in `Template.x.destroyed`). Your way is fine as long as there will only ever be one instance of the template (although I'd make the `someHelper` just a regular function, not a helper)